# Error in a .g.cs file?

Tags: c#, build

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'BreadcrumbLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) YOU_CAN'T_KNOW_THE_PATH_OR_NAME.g.cs    16  7   someWPFapp
```

And the troublesome line is:

```
using BreadcrumbLib;
```

Yesterday I have removed that project (BreadcrumbLib) from my solution and the main project worked fine.
Today it doesn't work.

What can I do about this?
What piece of forsaken information makes Visual Studio or whatever program builds the .g.cs files put that reference there?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Try doing a clean. If that doesn't work, delete the bin obj directories in your solution, then do a full rebuild. Make sure none of your XAML files are referencing that component (which is what's generating the .g.cs file).

Comment: +1 for what @Jeff says (I answered a phone call while typing mine!)

Comment: This worked... But why did my project build yesterday (on another machine) **after** I removed BreadcrumbLib?

Comment: Which worked? Clean/rebuild? or removing a xaml file reference? I would suspect it worked yesterday because BreadcrumLib was still in your bin or obj build directory, even though you removed the reference.

Comment: It was indeed a reference in the XAML.

Comment: A note for anyone with similar issues: I had to remove a reference from file 'b' in order to remove the error from file 'a'. So just keep looking (find all helps)

Comment: Just to clarify this, do you delete both the bin and the obj folders? I presume the answer is yes.

Comment: After changing the namespace in `MainWindow.xaml` don't forget to do the same in `App.xaml`.

Comment: For me, the problem was that I had renamed a Model, but the reference to the model in a view file had not been automatically renamed by VS.

Answer (score 33):

The .g.cs files in my projects are typically generated from XAML.

Check that the BreadcrumbLib isn't referenced in the xmlns references in any of your XAML files.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Anyway the xaml compiler should warn about an error at the xaml not at the g.cs

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me too because I moved some of my Xaml content to a sub userControl in a different folder, and Resharper moved the Xmlns references for me.

However, instead of using the Xmlns reference that was used before (specifically: xmlns:ms="clr-namespace:Mindscape.WpfElements.Charting;assembly=Mindscape.WpfElements"), ReSharper replaced it with the following:

```
xmlns:ms="http://namespaces.mindscape.co.nz/wpf"
```

I replaced the incorrect reference with the old correct one. That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

Just got this error message.

None of the answer here solved my issue, but I looked at my warnings message and saw that one of the project was build in .NET 4.7 and the other in 4.5. I put all project on the same version, build and now I'am happy!

Comment: I had NuGet package version conflicts between some projects, including test projects.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue as well. For me the problem was that a rename didn't go through all the way in the razor files, so the g.cs files kept getting generated with the old name.

I solved it by checking the related .razor file for errors and fixing them manually.

Comment: same here. I did a rename from `IdentityUser` to `ApplicationUser`. The pages that were failing with `g.cs` error was due to the using namespace of my `ApplicationUser` needed to be added.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone, like myself, encounters this issue, the cause for my issue was that my "GlobalStyles.xaml" resource dictionary was referencing the removed namesapce, and for some reason it showed up as an include in the MainWindow.g.cs file.  Removing the reference in the resource dictionary file fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

This just happened to me. My issue was that I had spaces in my `x:Name`. Once I removed the spaces and cleaned the solution it worked fine.

**Incorrect**

```
<button Text="Check In" x:Name="Check In">
```

**Correct**

```
<button Text="Check In" x:Name="CheckIn">
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error. The root cause was that I had renamed several of the viewModels and as it turned out my find & replace was not complete.

I resolved the issue by looking for the offending view model name in the error message, did a global search and replace in my views (not the .g.cs file). and the issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced the same issue,

I had a custom control i created in a nuget, and the generated xmal class just didn't like the namespace involved. It turns the control had a namespace of `xxx.yyy.zzz.Name` and my project had a namespace in it, `eee.fff.yyy...` (notice the `yyy`) it just got completely confused and the only recourse was to refactor the namespaces in the parent app.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into g.cs issues and deleting /bin and /obj did not help. If you renamed namespaces or classes, manually open each .cshtml file (double clicking the error will not do this in VS 2022 for some reason) and make sure the .cshtml has no syntax errors. In my case, I was pointing @model to the previous namespace.. missed these when using the replace tool and my various find/replace lookups.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33872481)

Comment: This entire thread is collective g.cs issues, landed on this result from a similar g.cs search query... not sure recommending deletion for a comment that points out a resolution to an unclear VS issue related to the original question makes sense, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but my issue was that I had removed a couple of folders/namespaces from a WPF UI library, and forgotten to remove the corresponding XmlnsDefinition entries from the library's AssemblyInfo.cs file.  I had had them all pointing to "http://schemas.foo.com/ui" to make it easier to reference in .xaml files, like so:

```
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://schemas.foo.com/ui", "ui")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.foo.com/ui", "Foo.UI.Common.Behaviors")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.foo.com/ui", "Foo.UI.Common.Converters")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.foo.com/ui", "Foo.UI.Common.Commands")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.foo.com/ui", "Foo.UI.Common.ViewModels")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.foo.com/ui", "Foo.UI.Common.UserControls")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.foo.com/ui", "Foo.UI.Common.Extensions")]
```

in AssemblyInfo.cs, and:

```
xmlns:ui="http://schemas.foo.com/foo/ui/"
```

in MainWindow.xaml.

I removed ViewModels and Commands, but forgot to remove the [assembly:] attributes, so it was looking for them when I rebuilt.  Removed the offending lines, et voila.

Figured I'd share for anyone else who did stuff like this and might be scratching their heads.

Answer (score 0):

My case is a little different. I have a WPF project and I've created a custom Panel like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MegaMenu
{
    public class MegaMenu : Panel
    {
```

My .xaml file looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MegaMenu.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MegaMenu"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"

        >
    <local:MegaMenu>
        <TextBox Width="50" Height="20" Text="First"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="50" Height="20" Text="Second"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="50" Height="20" Text="Third"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="50" Height="20" Text="Fourth"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="50" Height="20" Text="Fifth"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="50" Height="20" Text="Sixth"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="50" Height="20" Text="Seventh"></TextBox>
    </local:MegaMenu>
</Window>
```

This give's me the error in `g.cs` file blah blah. So it seems *this issue happens when the namespace name is the same as the class name*. I have to change them to below which caused the error gone.

.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MegaMenu
{
    public class MegaMenuPanel : Panel
    {
```

xaml file

```
<Window x:Class="MegaMenu.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MegaMenu"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"

        >
    <local:MegaMenuPanel>
        <TextBox Width="50" Height="20" Text="First"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="50" Height="20" Text="Second"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="50" Height="20" Text="Third"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="50" Height="20" Text="Fourth"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="50" Height="20" Text="Fifth"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="50" Height="20" Text="Sixth"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="50" Height="20" Text="Seventh"></TextBox>
    </local:MegaMenuPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I was tried to name a xaml control using x:Name , and forgot , and kept it as x:Name="" . The compiler was keep on throwing error. Give proper name or remove that empty string solves the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was not using WPF but got this error because I forgot to change the namespace in the @inject part of my razor view.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error down grading a `.NET 6` project to `.NET 4.8`.

By default `.NET 6` added into my `.csproj`     `<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>` which if I removed forced me add the `using` statements manually which resolved my issue of a phantom `using` thinking it was needed when it wasn't and couldn't be found.