# Why am I getting error messages against a namespace that isn't even referenced?

Tags: c#, xaml

A few years ago someone asked here a question about [Error in a .g.cs file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846237/error-in-a-g-cs-file) I tried what the answer was. I cleaned the project and the solution, twice. It failed to clear the error. I even deleted the bin folder and got back into VS and did a Rebuild Solution. That failed as well. I still get this error:

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Assets' does not exist in the namespace 'CoreFramework' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The Assets is a folder within the project. But as it is, it isn't even referenced in either the .cs file nor in the XAML. So why is it that when the C# compiler runs, it MUST referenced something the code doesn't? I'm at a loss to find a way to fix what VS won't let me get to.

I'm working in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Have you looked under [References](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx) in the Solution Explorer?

Comment: No I hadn't. Just did. The Assets folder isn't referenced there.

Comment: [This guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419905/dont-understand-why-were-getting-error-cs0234/35440678) fixed the same error by deleting everything in `obj`, not just `bin`. edit: oh that's you? lol, I guess ignore this comment..

Comment: I've actually created batch files to delete bin and obj for my projects when they go nuts since Clean doesn't do anything helpful. There are dozens of folders since my solution has 20 projects, so a batch is the quickest to nuke it all.

Comment: That might be what I'll have to do, although this solution is pretty small compared to yours. Just two projects and the second one is for unit tests. I tried deleting the bin and obj folders, then rebooted my PC. It did reduce the number of errors, but I'm still getting two of them, with that same error message.