# Building XAML file in visual Studio results in an error on a line that does not exist

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Please look at the complete code in my .xaml-file. As you can see it only has 10 lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage BackgroundColor="Black"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageTest"             
             x:Class="ImageTest.ImagePage">

    <Button Image="clock.png" x:Name="btn" />

</ContentPage>
```

When i try to build my project, i get the following error message:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Position 12:16. 
Type EmbeddedImage not found in xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms ImageTest

D:\Mobile Apps\Mosh\ImageTest\ImageTest\ImageTest\ImagePage.xaml    12
```

Why is Visual Studio giving me an error on a line that does not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your XAML file is compiled into a .g.cs file on build time. When executed, this compiled file throws the error, so Visual Studio is showing the error for the compiled file and line numbers won't apply.

If you altered the file, you should clean-build/rebuild your solution in order to remove old compiled files.
([Error in a .g.cs file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846237/error-in-a-g-cs-file))

Comment: Great, that fixes this problem, thanx a lot! My next problem is a new error: The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'ImageTest, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'ImageTest.dll'. Let's see how to fix that one :)